# Failed to show all datalist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am actually getting stuck to get my all datalist. I had to use nested "Include" as a child but not working. I am tried `.Include(x => x.Posts.Select(q => q.Postedpics ))` but get error because maybe approch is not right way. below, there I given class and relationship data for better understand. here is:-

`model Class`

```
AppUser.cs
 public class AppUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
//Photo.cs
 public class Photo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    }
//Post.cs
 public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Postedpic> Postedpics { get; set; }
       
    }
//Postedpic.cs
 public class Postedpic
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public Post Post { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
    }
```

`model DTO`

```
//AppUserDto.cs
 public class AppUserDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PhotoDto> Photos { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PostDto> Posts { get; set; }
    }

//Similarly created **PostDto.cs** , **PhotoDto.cs** and **PostedpicDto.cs**
```

```
//userRepository
   public async Task<IEnumerable<AppUser>> GetUsersAsync()
        {
           return await _context.Users
           .Include(p=>p.Photos)
           .Include(p=>p.Posts).  //here maybe change something. but i don't understand.
            ToListAsync();
        }

//Controller
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppUserDto>>> GetUsers()
        {

         var users = await _userRepository.GetUsersAsync();
         var usertoreturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MemberDto>>(users);
         return Ok(usertoreturn);
            
        }
```

`mapper`

```
CreateMap<AppUser,AppUserDto>();
            CreateMap<Photo,PhotoDto>();
            CreateMap<Post,PostDto>();
            CreateMap<Postedpic,PostedpicDto>();
```

When I run this program and test postman then I found this type of json data output but I not found `"postedpics": []` data list as like `Photos` and `Post`.

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "lisa",
        "photoUrl": null,
       
        "photos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "url": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/54.jpg",
                "isMain": true
            }
        ],
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "this is good",
                "photoUrl2": null,
                "postedpics": []
            }
        ]
    },
```

My goal is want to show `"postedpics": []` data list but how I will do that. I am beginner please help.

Comment: Have you read documentation? [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels)

Comment: Try to check  the structure,the postedpics is inside `Post` rather than `AppUser`.

Comment: @YiyiYou If i do that then how i will make the relation AppUser and Post? I am actually want ```AppUser``` Has many ```Post``` on the other hand ```Post``` has Many ```postedpics``` and I want to show All Of ```Post``` ```AppUser``` and ```Postedpic``` data as a same time.

Comment: Try to refer to the link what `Svyatoslav Danyliv` shared above.

Comment: @YiyiYou according to link refferd link when i used  **ThenInclude(p=>p.Postedpic)** then found error:- ```ICollection<Post>' does not contain a definition for 'Postedpic' and no accessible extension method 'Postedpic' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Post>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ```

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried, but found error.  I used  ```return await _context.Users
            .Include(p=>p.Photos)
            .Include(p=>p.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Postedpic).
            SingleOrDefaultAsync(t=>t.UserName==username);```